# UIAlertController + UIProgressView + macCatalyst

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I use the following simple class to display an alert view with a progress bar in my iOS app. It is ok, but when I try to use the same code in an app built for macOS, the progress bar is not visible (see the attached images).

What should I change to have the progress bar even on the macOS?

[image: Progress bar on iOS]

[image: Progress bar on macOS]

```
protocol ProgressDelegate: class {
    func onProgressCanceled()
}

class ProgressAlert {

private let alert: UIAlertController
private var progressBar: UIProgressView

init(title: String, delegate: ProgressDelegate?) {
    
    alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    progressBar = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progressBar.tintColor = Theme.appColor
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { alertAction in
        delegate?.onProgressCanceled()
    })
}

func present(from uivc: UIViewController) {
    
    uivc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        
        let margin: CGFloat = 16.0
        let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: 56.0,
                          width: self.alert.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0, height: 2.0)
        self.progressBar.frame = rect
        self.alert.view.addSubview(self.progressBar)
    })
}

func dismiss(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    
    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
}

func setProgress(_ value: Float) {
    progressBar.setProgress(value, animated: true)
    print("Updating download: \(value)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress bar is actually added as expected, but Mac Catalyst hides the `UIAlertController` view altogether and presents a native macOS `NSAlert` instead.

You can see the original alert that has the progress bar by setting `alert.view.isHidden` to `false`:

[image: 1]

Keep in mind that you shouldn't have added a custom view to the alert controller in the first place. Quoting from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller):

> Important
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
> support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
> **must not be modified**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What are the best practices to display a cancellable dialogue with a progress bar?

Comment: No native solution that I'm aware of for iOS. On macOS, you can use `NSAlert` and a progress indicator as the [`accessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsalert/1530575-accessoryview). But if you want a generic solution for iOS & macOS I guess a custom dialog is the way to go.